# How could I gracefully shut down a Service activator created with the kotlin suspend function in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to use Spring Integration and Kotlin Coroutine together. Functionally, it works well and I'm satisfied. However, when the Spring Integration application is stopped, the suspend function is canceled in the middle. This seems to be the same behavior as the Reactive stream being canceled in the middle when I don't give the server.shutdown=graceful option in Spring Webflux, because if I cause blocking in the suspend function, it will be gracefully shut down.

Doesn't Spring Integration support graceful shutdown for reactive, and if so, what configuration or implementation can I use to make it happen?

Thank you!

Here is the code I tested:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan
class TestConfiguration {
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestConfiguration::class.java)

    @Bean
    fun testChannel() = DirectChannel()

    @Bean
    fun router() = coRouter {
        POST("/test", this@TestConfiguration::handle)
    }

    private suspend fun handle(request: ServerRequest): ServerResponse {
        val message = object : Message<String> {
            override fun getPayload(): String {
                return "test"
            }

            override fun getHeaders(): MessageHeaders {
                return MessageHeaders(emptyMap())
            }
        }

        testChannel().send(message)

        return ServerResponse.ok().buildAndAwait()
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "testChannel")
    suspend fun handler1(payload: String) {
        repeat(1000) {
            log.info("delay $it")
            Thread.sleep(100)
        }
    }
}
```

I searched the github issue and documentation to find out if Spring Integration supports graceful shutdown, but I couldn't find anything other than "Orderly Shutdown".

Since I use Coroutine, creating a separate coroutineScope and waiting for the job to end via Shutdown hook is one way of graceful shutdown, but it creates a repetitive code, so I would like to know if Spring Integration provides a graceful shutdown setting like Webflux.

Comment: This is probably more question to Kotlin Coroutines where their dispatcher reacts to an application close and therefore it cancels all the current executions.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thank you for the reply!

I don't think it's just a Coroutine issue, because the same thing happens when I run the Service Activator as a Reactor. The same thing happens when I use Mono's delayElement.